# Ruta absoluta en una variable bash

Tags: bash, variables, rutas

Tengo un ejercicio en el que debo solicitar rutas absolutas de tres directorios en una terminal, una IP de un host y un directorio de ese host, donde debo copiar los tres primeros directorios, mi intento es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=""
dir2=""
dir3=""
dirDest=""
ip=""
echo "COPIA DE DIRECTORIOS POR SSH"
read -p"Primer directorio a copiar (Ruta absoluta): " dir1
read -p "Segundo directorio a copiar (Ruta absoluta): " dir2
read -p "Tercer directorio a copiar (Ruta absoluta): " dir3
read -p "Directorio de destino (Ruta absoluta): " dirDest
read -p "Indique IP del host: " ip

scp -pr "$dir1 $ip:$dirDest"
scp -pr "$dir2 $ip:$dirDest"
scp -pr "$dir3 $ip:$dirDest"
```

El problema es que me sale el siguiente error: `´ : not valid identifiered:` dirX` siendo la X las variaciones del nombre de las variables y la variable me la muestra vacía. 
La pregunta es: ¿Como hago que me tome las rutas absolutas y la guarde en las variables?

Comment: Tu código me corre bien. Quizás es porque tienes un caracter de más. Trata de reescribir tu código o copiar el que pusiste en tu propia pregunta.

Comment: Pues si, lo escribí desde cero (como por 3ra vez) y funcionó, pero el `.sh` del que copié el código de la pregunta, sigue tirando el mismo error, algún caracter oculto que lo arruinaba. En fin. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y por aclararme que no estaba perdido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recientemente he visto que hay varios problemas por caracteres ocultos. Mi sospecha es que, en lo que se usan los metacomandos, ya sea para cambiar de pestañas, llevar el cursor al inicio, cambiar de ventanas, etc., se inserta un caracter de más.

Para esto es buena idea aplicar un `cat -A <archivo problematico>` para ver todos los caracteres que tiene, incluso los ocultos.

Comment: Comentando con un compañero de clases que tiene bastante mas experiencia me comentó exactamente lo mismo, los ocultos que pudieran generarse por haber usado el `winscp` para la edición, u otra acción con la VM donde estoy trabajando con la consola. Así que muy buen comentario y aporte! Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Vizz3rdriX Que bueno que te hayan informado sobre eso. También puedes aplicar otras estrategias como usar `hd`, `od`, o abrir el archivo con `vim` o `nano` o eliminar caracteres que no estén en un rango.